# Asp.net app_data connect db

Tags: asp.net, app-data

I am having sql server express edition local database in app_data folder.

How can i connect SQL Server Management Studio Expres with that db to execute sql scripts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Management Studio, right click databases, attach database and point to your mdf file.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an MDF file, SQL Management Studio can't open it.

This article might help: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/22/recipe-deploying-a-sql-database-to-a-remote-hosting-environment-part-1.aspx